# Adding User Defined Runtime Attributes?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, pixate

Is there a way to add user defined runtime attributes to a button in Xamarin's storyboard designer?

I'm trying to get [Pixate Freestyle](https://github.com/Pixate/Xamarin-PixateFreestyle) to work and need to define the attributes. I can only find the place to define them within xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a Xamarin Forms project and I figured out that on each platform, there is a method to update the style for a Control. The way I used to do this is something like this:

```
PixateFreestyle.SetStyleId(view, styleId);
```

or

```
PixateFreestyle.SetClassId(view, classId);
```

Where view is any UIView you want to style ann styleId/classId is a string with the style name in your default.css

Hope this works for you

This is where I based my project

[XamarinForms-PixateFreestyle](https://github.com/flashvnn/XamarinForms-PixateFreestyle)